# Can not save picture from intent

Tags: android, android-camera, android-10.0, redmi-device

I have a project witch have permission to camera and storage.

When the user click in some buttons the camera will be open by intent and  take picture then saved it in the device  to add it to firebase storage.

This operation  was successful on most devices, but in **Redmi A8(Android 10 , MIUI 12.0.1)** it
was failed , the camera open then the application stop , maybe it failed to save the picture or failed to get it in ActicityResult.

*Who I can solve it ?*

**Note:** This is a part of methods in my code.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                        "com.apps.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        }
    }
```

```
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  
                ".jpg",         
                storageDir     
        );

        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
                //showImage.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(f));
                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

                uploadImageToFirebase(f.getName(), contentUri);


            }

        }


    }
```

```
    private void uploadImageToFirebase(String name, Uri contentUri) {
        final StorageReference image = storageReference.child("pictures/" + name);
        image.putFile(contentUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                image.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        database.getReference().child("Shifts").child(empId+"").
                                child(shiftKey).child(shiftImageType).setValue(uri+"");
                        alertDialog.dismiss();


                    }
                });

                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity() , MainActivity.class));
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: `catch (IOException ex) {

            }` Handle the exception! Print the stack trace and display a Toast() to inform the user. Then stop/return. Dont continue like you do now.

Comment: @blackapps who should the code become?